# How do I turn an array of nullable items into a nullable array based on whether any of the items are null?

Tags: swift

I have an array of nullable items which may or may not have any `nil`s in it:

```
let source = [1, 2, 3] as [Int?]
// or
let source = [1, 2, nil] as [Int?]
```

I want to turn it into an `[Int]?` with the values as `Int`s if no items are `nil` or `nil` if any item is `nil`.

What's the idiomatic way to do this?

Things I've tried:

```
// fails with: fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes 
let result = source as? [Int]
```

and:

```
func toNonNullable<T>(array: [T?]) -> [T]? {
    if array.filter({$0 == nil}).count != 0 {
        return nil;
    }

    return array.map({$0!}) 
}

// This works, but seems likey to be non-idiomatic (as well as being ineffecient). 
let result = toNonNullable(source)
```

Comment: But the same variable cannot be an `[Int]` or `nil` - unless it is an `[Int]?`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes it is. I'll edit to make that clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would write it:

```
let source = [1, 2, nil] as [Int?]
var result : [Int]? = {
    for i in source {
        if i == nil {
            return nil
        }
    }
    return source.map {$0!}
}()
```

But that doesn't really meet your "inefficient" consideration. Someone has to look through the array to see if it contains nil, so nothing is lost by looping and doing that; but the inefficiency is that we loop twice, because `map` is a loop. If you really hate that, here's a way out:

```
var result : [Int]? = {
    var temp = [Int]()
    for i in source {
        if let i = i {
            temp.append(i)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    return temp
}()
```

Lots of very idiomatic Swifties in those formulations, I think!