# Extending Array to append SKTextures

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sktexture

Being fairly new to Swift I decided I would look at extending `Array` (or more specifically `[SKTexture]` Arrays of SKTexture) with a function to add a specified number of frames from the application bundle.

```
// FRAMES
FuzzyRabbit_0001@2x.png
FuzzyRabbit_0002@2x.png
FuzzyRabbit_0003@2x.png
FuzzyRabbit_0004@2x.png

// CALL
var rabbitTextures = [SKTexture]()
self.rabbitTextures.textureFromFrames("FuzzyRabbit", count: 4)
```

My first attempt is listed below, I am getting the error `Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(SKTexture!)'` which from looking at the function `fuzzyPush` is because I am trying to append an `SKTexture` rather than the generic `T`.

Is this possible, or am I limited by the fact that I don't want the function to be generic but rather specific to Arrays of `SKTexture`.

```
extension Array {

    // ONLY SKTexture
    mutating func textureFromFrames(imageName: String, count: Int) {
        if !(self[0] is SKTexture) { return }
        for index in 1...count {
            let image = String(format: "\(imageName)_%04d", index)
            let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: image)
            self.append(texture) // ERROR: Cannot invoke append with an argument list of type SKTexture!
        }
    }

    // WORKS FINE
    mutating func fuzzyPush(newItem: T) {
        self.append(newItem)
    }
}
```

I was just curious if this is something I could do with an extension, its not a problem as I have this as a function that takes 3 parameters (imageName, count, arrayToAppend) so I can quite easily use that.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929497/how-can-i-create-an-extension-method-that-only-applies-to-arrays-of-nullable-ite and the references in the comments. You cannot write an extension method only for a specific type of array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This extension is not possible to write today. You cannot apply an extension method to only certain types of arrays.

There are two good solutions. You can use a HAS-A pattern by creating a struct (`TextureList`) that contains a `[SKTexture]`, or you can use a function.

Comment: So its a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350941/is-it-possible-to-make-an-array-extension-in-swift-that-is-restricted-to-one-cla ?

Comment: Agreed. This is a duplicate.

Comment: And guess who answered that  one :)

Comment: Rob, thank you for your answer and the pointer to the duplicate. Much appreciated Sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace :

```
self.append(texture)
```

with

```
self.append(texture as T)
```

I checked this on an array of strings though and it worked.
About the first check add another check to see if the array is empty otherwise the `self[0] is SKTexture` will fail.

This is the code I tested on an online swift compiler (`SKTexture` was not available obviously) :

```
extension Array {

    mutating func textureFromFrames(imageName: String, count: Int) {
        for index in 1...count {
            let image = String(format: "\(imageName)_%04d", index)
            self.append(image as T) 
        }
    }
}


var arr = Array<String>()
arr.textureFromFrames("testing", count:4)

for tmp in arr {
    println("\(tmp)")
}
```